# after upgrading to xcode 3.2, can I still build projects into 3.1 simulator?

Tags: xcode, build-process, xcode3.2

I upgraded to xcode 3.2 and now the build options from the drop down menu on the upper left of the main window in xcode are limited to only 3.2 versions of the sdk, however if I open a project up that was built in the previous version those options are still there(or at least 3.1.2 is) anyway to get that option into a project built in the new 3.2 sdk?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit `Cmd+I` when selecting the project.

[image]
<sub>(source: [vlfeat.org](http://www.vlfeat.org/images/using-xcode-dylib.png))</sub>

In the Info window, find "Base SDK", then choose "Simulator - iPhone OS 3.1.2"